API to get file from S3 bucket going in pending state again and again
I have a nodejs express server setup on Digital Ocean droplet. I have an api which is hitting the following function to read data from aws s3. This api is going into pending state and giving 504 gateway timeout error. But if I restart my server the things work fine. Apart from this api all the other apis are working fine on the server.
// configuration setup
const configuration = {
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
  },
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
  maxAttempts: 3, // retry mechanism
  requestTimeout: 60000, // timeout settings
  maxConnections: 50,       // Example: setting a maximum number of connections


};

//final function

exports.readFileFromS3 = async (file_id) => {
  let read_stream = null;
  let error = null;
  try {
    const downloadParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: file_id
    };
    const command = new GetObjectCommand(downloadParams);
    const response = await S3Client.send(command);
    read_stream = response.Body;
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }
  return { read_stream, error };
};




What could be the possible reason for the issue and how should I fix it?
